# Import path difference using "build" and "tool compile"

Tags: go

I'm trying to compile this [example](https://github.com/nats-io/go-nats/blob/master/examples/nats-sub.go) (which is saved as `main.go` in current working dir):

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "log"
    "runtime"

    "github.com/nats-io/go-nats"
)

// rest of the code
```

This works:

```
$ go build ./
```

But this does not:

```
$ go tool compile -o main.o main.go
main.go:8:2: can't find import: "github.com/nats-io/go-nats"
```

Both of examples above were run on the same terminal with same environment variables, so I don't understand why the 2nd one does not work. I've tried `-D` and `-I` parameters with various directories as `$GOPATH`, `$GOPATH/src` and so on with no success.

I know what it's considered best practice to not use `go tool compile` and so on, but my goal is to add my go source to existing C++ makefile project and useage of `go tool` will make it more consistent.

Comment: Did you try `"github.com/nats-io/go-nats"`?

Comment: @FrankAK what do you mean? Where should I try this?

Comment: in your terminal

Comment: Did you try `go get "github.com/nats-io/go-nats"`?

Comment: Yes, `"github.com/nats-io/go-nats"` is installed into my `$GOPATH` and it's visible by `go build`, but not by `go tool compile`.

Comment: Have you tried using the -D or -I flag? [docs](https://golang.org/cmd/compile/)

Comment: @dev.bmax thanks for documentation link, it's described better than in help of command itself. I'll write an answer to my question.

Answer (score 7):

Correct syntax of `go tool compile` is as follows:

```sh
go tool compile -I $GOPATH/pkg/linux_amd64 -o main.o main.go
```

The problem was that by default, `compile` performs lookup only in `$GOROOT` and ignores `$GOPATH`.

Comment: Is this answer still relevant now that Go uses modules?

Comment: 425nesp no idea, I haven't used go for like 4 years now. I will accept edits if this one is not relevant though.